# Schema.Types.ObjectId undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Got the following error for mongoose schema:

```
  _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined
```

I have tried both mongoose 5.08 and 5.09. Both failed.

Any response would be appreciated.
Thanks.
Richard

Comment: How is `Schema` set in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var mongoSchema = mongoose.Schema;

  var user = new mongoSchema({
    ref_id: {
       type: mongoSchema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'client'
    }
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

Comment: sorry i dont have to hand. it was to do with using typegoose, which has given me all kinds of other issues.